# Understanding CSS Animation Keyframe Percentages

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

Am I misunderstanding the following?

```
@keyframes look {
  0%,
  40%, /* 4s */
  47.5%, /* 4.75s */
  100% /* 10s */ {
  }

  42.5% /* 4.25s */ {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  45% /* 4.5s */ {
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
}
```

At a total duration of 10s, I interpret the above as meaning, from 0s  (0%) to 4s (40%), nothing happens, then at 4s the element moves to the left and arrives at the left at 4.25s (42.5%), at which point it moves over to the right and arrives at 4.5s (45%), finally it arrives back to its original position at 4.75s (47.5%) and stays there till the 10s (100%) is up.

---

My issue is that the element appears to start slowly moving immediately, rather than waiting then quickly moving to the left then right then back. This makes me think I must be misunderstanding something about the way css moves from percentage block to percentage block.

Christopher Webb

Comment: You're almost correct in thinking that but animations aren't linear by default, they "ease" in and out. Here are two excellent articles I read a while ago that I think will help in your case https://www.joshwcomeau.com/animation/css-transitions/#timing-functions-2 and https://www.joshwcomeau.com/animation/keyframe-animations/ (not my website)

Comment: I just added transform: translateX(0); to the previously-empty first percentage block and now it appears to be working the way I expected it to in the first place.